# Developer name as client name in iTunes store

Tags: ios4, itunes

We have launched an app for a client under our own company name as the developer on the App store. Our client has now asked us to change the name of the developer listed to be shown as theirs.

I've read that this can be done - BUT would this change only apply to the single client app or to ALL apps produced by us?

We are happy to agree to a change, as long as it only effects their app and not our other clients.

I understand that we have to contact Apple about this.

Comment: I have this same problem; did you ever figure out the answer to this?